# Stripe add invoice item to customer not working on server

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Right now I’m making a call to add an invoice item to a customer (as a pending item) with the code below. This works completely fine in my local and creates the item, although when I deploy it to our server, the call fails with a 500 error. All of my other calls to Stripe work just fine including creating an invoice, a customer, and about 30 other calls. For some reason this is the only one that isn’t returning any response and I’m struggling to debug what the issue is.

Here's the call in PHP:

```
$data = array(
  "customer" => "$customer_id",
  "amount" => $amount*100,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "description" => "$description"
);
if ($invoice_id) {
  $data["invoice"] = $invoice_id;
}
$invoice_item = \Stripe\Invoiceitem::create($data);
```

I have the call wrapped in a try/catch and am using all the potential errors Stripe provides in it's documentation and its bypassing the catch and throwing a 500.

Comment: Are you sure you catch all errors in the code? what is the exact error you get back, which error message is in it?

Comment: The call returns a 500 from Stripe's side or your own server? can you add ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); error_reporting(E_ALL); to your script or review your error log and share the full error?

Comment: After adding those 2 statements, it seems that it's missing the Class 'Stripe\Invoiceitem', but I'm installing Stripe from composer on Heroku and getting version 5.7 so I'm not sure why that would be...

Answer (score 0):

This issue came down to the capitalization on PHP 5.6 vs PHP 7.0 where 'Invoiceitem' on PHP 7.0 needed to be 'InvoiceItem' on PHP 7.0.